# How to use git subtree to add local repo?

Tags: git, git-subtree

Say I have a dir that is already a git repo "sub", now I want it to be a subtree of my newly created super directory "sup".

I've searched the document, but all the tutorials are about adding a remote repo or split from the existing commits. How can I add the existed git repo to the main git repo?

Using `git subtree add --prefix=sub sub` would give the warning sub already exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, depending on what you expect.

1. Add sub repo as a submodule. The repos stay independent
2. Add sub repo as a subtree of this subrepo. Its histories become merged

---

For 1, you want to use git submodule. Specifically,

In your sup directory (already initialized with git init) you run:

```
git submodule add location-of-sub
```

it will clone the sub repo into the sup repo. You can then remove the sub repo if it is located somewhere else.

Note that submodules still act as different repos than the top repo.

See the documentation for submodules:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

---

For 2, it is a bit more convoluted.

First you fetch the commits of the other repo:

```
# add remote
git remote add sub <locationofsubrepo>
# fetch commits
git fetch
# create local branch with sub
git checkout -b sub_branch sub/master
# switch to master
git checkout master
# now, merge commit as a subdirectory
git read-tree --prefix=sub/ -u sub_branch
```

you can in the future keep pulling from sub, and it will be merged into sup

Comment: 'git remote add sub sub'; 'git fetch sub'. Then have to delete the local dir sub. Also if the git log is to be reserved, I guess I should use 'git merge -s ours --no-commit'

Comment: Read many articles extolling the virtues **subtrees** have over **submodules**, but ultimately I wasted a lot of time attempting to adopt the _convulated_ paradigm described in the v1 book. The v2 book makes a vague reference to the complexity but doesn't describe the problem -- pushing changes merged from the master's subtree to the branch will result in the branch's upstream repo having *all of the objects* from the local repository including what's referenced by _master_.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. But one thing to note with more recent versions of git (v2.38.1 for me): the "file" protocol is blocked by default and using the above submodule command will get you an error something to the effect of `Cloning into '/tmp/repo1/sub'...
fatal: transport 'file' not allowed fatal: clone of '/tmp/repo2' into submodule path '/tmp/repo1/sub' failed`. To avoid this, it is necessary to use the `-c` option to override the `protocol.file.allow` config property, e.g. `git -c protocol.file.allow=always submodule add --name subrepo /tmp/repo2 path-under-parent-repo`